How does the united-atom description work?
I'd like to know something regarding the united-atom approximation:
Consider a homonuclear diatomic molecule e.g. $\mathrm{N}_2$. One can obtain its "equivalent" atom that has a nucleus of charge $2Z=N$ where $N$ is the amount of electrons found in the molecule. In the case of $\mathrm{N}_2$, the atom we'd like to find has $2Z= 14$ as an atomic number. It would be silicon. However, given that, for instance, $\mathrm{CO}$ has $8+6=14$ electrons as well, would silicon be the equivalent atom too? Have you seen such an approximation before? English is not my native language and I can't find anything related online.

The electronic structure of the N2 molecule looks nothing like the electronic structure of Si. It just doesn't work that way.

I think a much better question is: "Where did you even get this crazy unified atom approximation from?" We need to know, before we can judge if it is applicable to your target use case.

The simplest case would be comparison of the molecular orbitals of a $\mathrm{H}{2}$ molecule with a $\mathrm{He}$ atom.  This has been done, looking at the low-lying orbitals as a function of function of the nuclear separation in $\mathrm{H}{2}$(zero separation corresponding to $\mathrm{He}$), but even that is a complicated computational problem.

No, silicon is not equivalent, electronically or chemically, to dinitrogen ($\mathrm{N}_2$).
The difference is that one has two nitrogen atoms and one is a silicon atom. Sure, the proton, neutron, and electron counts might be the same, but the way they are distributed is important too. Two nitrogen atoms can unbind and bind to something else, but silicon is one atom (meaning to "bind to something else", it would have to fission, which doesn't happen (citation: you are using a computer without dying)), and the valence electron structures are totally different.
As far as physics goes, sure, they have roughly the same mass (nuclear binding energy changes this slightly), and the same net charge, so if you throw one molecule of dinitrogen or one atom of silicon at an object with a set velocity you'll get roughly the same result. But in chemistry, that approximation is useless. Any chemist will tell you that dinitrogen and silicon behave in radically different ways, despite being made of the exact same stuff.

This was mainly a nuclear physics question. I couldn't find any helpful information online and it was mentioned in a class. I understand that chemically they have nothing to do with one another but I was given the example I posted as, well, an example provided by the professor. He didn't have time to answer my e mails so I asked here hoping someone would recognize the theory

@EduardoKuri Even in nuclear physics the separation between nucleons leads to different behaviors. Maybe it's an approximation that I'm not aware of but I've never used such an approximation; if your professor posted it as valid, then he will probably expect that you use it, so there you go.

I got suspicious that it was so easy. His notes were unclear but yes it's a weird approximation. We saw that indeed molecules with the same amount of electrons behave differently depending on bonding states, etc
